# Finding marginal distribution, unit sphere

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm asked to find the marginal distribution of $(X,Y)$ as $(X,Y,Z)$ is a point chosen uniformly on the unit sphere.

I've worked out that the joint density function $f_{XYZ}(x,y,z) = \frac{3}{4\pi}$ for $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1.$

I know how to find the marginal distribution when dealing with 2-dimensions, but I'm not sure how I should set up the integrals in this case.

Would this be the correct way to go,

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y \int_{z} f_{XYZ}(x,y,z) dzdydx,$$

or am I really computing the marginal distribution of $F_X(x)$ if I do that?

Also, I'm having some problems understanding the difference between finding the density function and distribution function in cases like this. To me, it seems to be the same method for both functions?

Comment: You're doing the right job. The distribution of the random variable $(X,Y)$ (which is a marginal in this case) must be a function of two real variables, say $(x,y)$; you must therefore "zap" the $z$ from $f_{XYZ}$ by averaging it out. So marginal density is $$f_{XY}(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb R}f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\operatorname dz,$$ whence (upon averagin in $x$ and $y$) your formula for $(X,Y)$'s distribution.

Comment: Note that "=" should read "$\leq$" in $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq1$.  I advise newbies to learn the Iverson--Knuth brackets that make the algebra much easier for this type of exercises.

Comment: About the "=", you are of course right! Will edit.

But if I would like to find $f_X(x)$, wouldn't I essentially compute the exact same thing? And is the density function and the distribution function the same thing in this case?

Comment: There is a big difference between a ball ($\leq1$) and a sphere ($=1$). If the original question is about the unit sphere then there cannot exist a 3-dimensional density function.

Comment: From context, they meant ball.

Comment: The confusion between sphere and ball that @Justpassingby mentions must be addressed before going further. Note that, even if (X,Y,Z) is uniform on the sphere (hence with no density), (X,Y) is distributed on the unit disk and has a density.

Comment: @OskarLimka Which context are you informed of?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is it even possible to find the marginal distribution if it is a sphere and therefore there is no joint density function?

Comment: @Justpassingby you're correct.  In fact, even assuming they meant ball (and I may be wrong) the density seems to be wrong (the $\pi$ should be in the denominator).  I now agree the question should be rephrased in the light of sphere vs ball distinction.

Comment: @vincefontaine you may still have a two-dimensional density concentrated on the sphere, but that wouldn't be a function in the usual calculus sense, it would be a "generalized function" or a "distribution" (in the sense of distribution theory).

Comment: That was my mistake, about the $\pi$, made an edit now.

Comment: @OskarLimka "or a "distribution" (in the sense of distribution theory)" Pleeease... Distributions à la Schwartz are not needed at all to attack such purely measure-theoretic questions.

Comment: So... what do I do here? :p Can I use the method as in Oskar's first comment?

Comment: Yes you follow the formula to integrate and obtain the joint pdf of $(X, Y)$: $\displaystyle \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} \frac {3} {4\pi} dz = \frac {3} {2\pi} \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ Note that they are not uniformly distributed inside the unit disk.

Comment: Do you know if the density function is the same as the distribution function in this case? Because the above solution gives the density function, right? And I'm wondering how to compute the joint distribution function... @BGM

Answer (score 3):

A uniform distribution on the sphere does not have a density function in three variables, but the marginal distribution for two of the three variables does have a density. It is obtained by expressing the area element of the sphere $\sin\theta d\varphi\wedge d\theta$ in new coordinates $x$ and $y$ and then normalizing.

$$\eqalign{
\sin^2\theta&=x^2+y^2\\
2\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta&=2xdx+2ydy\\
\sin\theta d\theta&=\frac{xdx+ydy}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\\
\varphi&=\arctan\left(\frac y x\right)\\
d\varphi&=\frac1{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}\left(\frac1xdy-\frac{y}{x^2}dx\right)\\
\sin\theta d\varphi\wedge d\theta&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}dx\wedge dy\\
}$$

This gives the density function

$$\frac1{2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$$

on the disk $x^2+y^2\leq1.$

Comment: I am not sure I follow, would you like to specify how you reached that result?

Comment: There was an error in my original volume element (missing $\sin\theta$); does this one look better?

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @Justpassingby Very impressive! Could you give a reference which presents the proof details? In multivariate statistics, we know that if $x$ has a density, then any marginal distribution of $x$ has a density. However, the fact that any marginal distribution of $x$ has a density can not guarantee the density existence of $x$; **uniform distribution in the surface of the unit** is such a case (counterexample), but I don't know how to proof it in details?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution (eschewing spherical coordinates) may be based on the approximation of the surface density by a bulk one as follows.  Let $h>0$ (destined to go to zero).  Consider the spherical shell $\Sigma_h$ of thickness $h$ about the sphere of radius $1$, i.e., the union of all the spheres of center $0$ and radius ranging between $1-h/2$ and $1+h/2$. Since this is a $3$-dimensional volume you may consider on it a uniform distribution (constant function) $f_{XYZ}^h\equiv c(h)$, with $c(h)$ constant in $x,y,z$ (but depending on $h$) chosen such that the integral of $f_{XYZ}^h$ is $1$. So $c(h)=1/\operatorname{vol}\Sigma_h$, which the following calculation reveals:
$$
\operatorname{vol}\Sigma_h
=
\int_{1-h/2}^{1+h/2}\int_{\partial B_0(\rho)}\operatorname d S\operatorname d\rho
=
\int_{1-h/2}^{1+h/2}4\pi\rho^2\operatorname d\rho
=
\frac{4\pi}3\Big(3h+\frac{h^3}4\Big)
=
4\pi h+\frac\pi3h^3
.
$$
As $h\to0$ the mass of the shell stays $1$, $c(h)\approx1/(4\pi{h}\to\infty$ and the $f_{XYZ}^h$ converges (weakly, or in the sense of distributions, or whatever your mathematical religion prescribes, but intuition is what matters) to $f_{XYZ}$.  Thanks to the integral being bounded to compute $f_{XY}$ it is legitimate to interchange limits (here the theory of distribution does come handy, but you can use geometric measure theory,if you prefer) to integrate $f^h_{XYZ}$ in $z$ first and then take $h\to0$.
The integration in $z$ rests on some simple geometry, for all $x,y$ such that $x^2+y^2<(1-h/2)^2$, the line passing through $(x,y)$ intersect the shell twice symmetrically about the $(x,y)$-plane. Looking at the upper half (and then doubling the result) the length of the segment is given by $S^+_h(x,y)-S^-_h(x,y)$ where $S_h^\pm$ are functions whose graphs are the outer and inner boundaries of the (upper half of the spherical) shell, respectively. Explicitly
$$S^\pm_h(x,y)=\sqrt{(1\pm h/2)^2-x^2-y^2}=:F(\pm h).$$
The auxiliary function $F$'s Taylor expansion of order $1$ about $0$ yields
$$
S^+_h(x,y)-S^-_h(x,y)
=
2F'(0)h+o(h)
=
\frac{h+o(h)}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}
,
$$
since $$F'(\xi)=\frac{1+\xi/2}{2\sqrt{(1+\xi/2)^2-x^2-y^2}}.$$
Multiplying this by $2$ (to take into account the lower half of the sphere)
and the density normalizing constant $c(h)$ we obtain
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f^h_{XYZ}(x,y,z)\operatorname dz
=
\frac{2h+o(h)}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}(4\pi h+\pi h^3/3)}
=
\frac{1+o(h^0)}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}(2\pi+\pi h^2/6)}
\to
\frac1{2\pi\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}
,\text{ as }h\to0
.
$$